# Is this vulnerable to XSS exploit?

Tags: xss, ajax

A typical ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://mywebsite/script?param=" + $("#field").val(),
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(response) {
      $("#id").html(response);
  },
 });
```

sends a parameter .
The parameter is filtered and sanitised on the server side.
The server returns a simple text response that is used to be displayed on the HTML page. 
However it is possible to intercept the response and include   tag.
Because the code uses $("#id").html(response) to display the response, the modified response, including  content will be executed .

As this occurs only when the server response is manipulated and before displayed on client, is this vulnerable to XSS ? How can this be exploited ?

As preventive method is it better to use $("#id").text(response);
instead of   $("#id").html(response) to ensure the response string, even when intercepted, is displayed as text ?

Comment: Man-in-the-Middle scenarios do not qualify as XSS vulnerabilities. If someone could modify the response then they could also modify the page itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have not given us enough information to determine if this is vulnerable to XSS. XSS occurs when a user input is displayed in a browser without proper escaping. For example:

```
$.ajax({
  $("#id").html($("#field").val());
 });
```

is vulnerable because the input value from `#field`is displayed in the browser without escaping.

If we look at your example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://mywebsite/script?param=" + $("#field").val(),
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(response) {
      $("#id").html(response);
  },
 });
```

a vulnerability exists if `response` contains all or parts of `#field`'s *unescaped* value. If `response` can only contain constant strings such as `OK` and `Error`, or if there was proper HTML escaping done on the user input, then you are secure. Otherwise, you have a vulnerability.

Comment: The $("#field").val() is escaped and sanitized on the server side. The response contains the sanitised value ( can even contain OK) . Can this response be exploited ? Should be better to have on client side $("#id").text(response) instead $("#id").html(response) to ensure strings are displayed as intended ?